# Output all cell colors from a range in Excel using Office Scripts

Tags: excel, office-scripts, excel-online, ms-office-script

Is there a way of extracting the fill colours from a range of cells into an array quickly and without looping through cells? Something like the code shown below. Am I missing something obvious?

```js
let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1')

//For cell values we can use
let values = sheet.getRange('A5:F35')?.getValues();

//but this doesn't work
let colors = sheet.getRange('A5:F35')?.getformat().getFill().getColor();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No native method from Microsoft gets `colors` for a range (multi-cells). A custom function makes it convenient.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let dataRange: ExcelScript.Range = selectedSheet.getRange("A4:B5")
    console.log(get_colors(dataRange))
}

function get_colors(dataRange: ExcelScript.Range) {
    let arrayResult: Object[] = []
    let rowCnt = dataRange.getRowCount()
    for(let rowIdx=0; rowIdx < rowCnt; rowIdx++){
        let arrayRow: String[] = []
        let row = dataRange.getRow(rowIdx)
        let colCnt = row.getColumnCount()
        for(let colIdx=0; colIdx < colCnt; colIdx++){
            // console.log(row.getColumn(colIdx).getFormat().getFill().getColor())
            arrayRow.push(row.getColumn(colIdx).getFormat().getFill().getColor())
        }
        arrayResult.push(arrayRow)
    }
    return arrayResult
}
```